# enable disable command link on entering input text

Tags: visualforce, jquery, visual

I have a command link in my vf page and an input text. I am trying to initially have the command link as disabled and when a user enters the text in the input then command link becomes enable and if the input text is empty then disable the command link. below is the code.Any solution using the controller or jquery is accepted. thanks

```
 <apex:commandLink value="Calculate End Date" action="{!calculateEndDate}"
                                           reRender="RecurrsiveDetails" ></apex:commandLink>
      <apex:input type="date" value="{!startDateRec}" label="Start Date" onchange="enableCalculateEndDate()"/>
```

Comment: look at `actionSupport` on the `apex:input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you could just bind the `disabled` attribute of your commandButton/outputLink, and use an actionSupport to rerender it when the input changes. In this case, since you really want to use a commandLink, you'll have to do something a little less direct because that component does not have a `disabled` attribute:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="linkPanel">
    <apex:commandLink id="calculateLink" value="Calculate End Date" action="{!calculateEndDate}" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(startDateRec))}" reRender="RecurrsiveDetails" />
    <apex:outputText value="Calculate End Date" rendered="{!ISBLANK(startDateRec)}"
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:input type="date" value="{!startDateRec}" label="Start Date" >
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="{!$Component.linkPanel}" />
</apex:input>
```

Comment: it gives error open quotes is needed for attribute disabled associated with element type <apex:commandlink />

Comment: Oops, yes it looks like I forgot to put double-quotes around the bind expression there. I have updated my answer.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please do not forget to mark it as solution :)

Comment: It still says in my command link as an error that the attribute disabled is not supported

Comment: <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
                            <apex:input type="date" value="{!endDateRec}" label="End Date"/>
                            <apex:commandLink value="Calculate End Date" action="{!calculateEndDate}"
                                              reRender="RecurrsiveDetails"></apex:commandLink>
                        </apex:outputPanel>     when i add your command link it gives the error

Comment: Sorry, another small oversight; I forgot that commandLink doesn't have a `disabled` attribute. You can use a commandButton or outputLink instead

Comment: No the question was posted because of the fact that I have to use a command link and not the command button. :)

Comment: Well, if you really need it to be a commandLink instead, please see the re-re-re-updated answer lol